# Is it possible to install RSYNC on Plesk shared hosting?

Tags: rsync, plesk

So I have a web hosting account that I have enabled SSH access on but there is no rsync command.

Is it possible to install it into the bin/ directory or some other way to then be able to use the rsync command?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would have to ask for rsync to be installed by the system administrator.  If you had full access to the system you could install it yourself (depending on the distribution of Linux).  I'm assuming this is a Linux box?

As the root user installing rsync should be as simple as:

Debian/Ubuntu
apt-get install rsync

Redhat/Centos
yum install rsync

Depending on the type of shell account you have enabled in Plesk you may need to add rsync to the list of allowed programs that your user can run (in a jailed shell or chroot).  The exact command is dependant on your version of Plesk.